# How to call upon Mute/Speaker control keys in Python. Dell latitude E7440

Tags: python, button, audio, speaker

I need help finding the mute key on the Dell that I'm using. I need to call upon the button press to do something in Python but I can't find any documentation regarding their names. The ultimate goal of this is to prevent users from muting their speakers. I will be using Python and plan to use Tkinter to block the button press.

Answer (score 1):

Using [PyHook](https://pypi.org/project/pyHook/) you can block Windows mouse and keyboard events.
The following is example code (for blocking keys during a pygame) that can be found [here.](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/553270-using-pyhook-to-block-windows-keys/) This seems to apply to your situation so very little modification is needed it seems.

```
import pyHook
import pygame

# create a keyboard hook
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    print 'MessageName:',event.MessageName
    print 'Message:',event.Message
    print 'Time:',event.Time
    print 'Window:',event.Window
    print 'WindowName:',event.WindowName
    print 'Ascii:', event.Ascii, chr(event.Ascii)
    print 'Key:', event.Key
    print 'KeyID:', event.KeyID
    print 'ScanCode:', event.ScanCode
    print 'Extended:', event.Extended
    print 'Injected:', event.Injected
    print 'Alt', event.Alt
    print 'Transition', event.Transition
    print '---'
    if event.Key.lower() in ['lwin', 'tab', 'lmenu']: #(CHANGE HERE TO BLOCK MUTE KEY)
        return False    # block these keys 
    else:
        # return True to pass the event to other handlers
        return True

# create a hook manager
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
# watch for all keyboard events
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
# set the hook
hm.HookKeyboard()

# initialize pygame and start the game loop
pygame.init()

while(1):
    pygame.event.pump()
```

I was assuming you were using windows but otherwise I have only personally seen [this linux version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pykeylogger/).

Comment: Thank you! this will be very useful. However, I'm still faced with the biggest problem which is finding out how to block the mute key. I couldn't find any documentation about how to call the in-built mute keys of USB and laptop keyboards. Would you have any idea of how to get the button-code? Perhaps through a script that prints the code of buttons pressed or simply a nice piece of documentation?